# NumPy: Iterating over items to right, bottom of given element w/ its index

Tags: python, numpy

Suppose I have a NumPy array like the following:

```
a b c d
e f g h
i j k l
m n o p
```

How could I iterate over it in the specific way below, given by the following pseudocode:

```
upperdiag = {a, b, c, e, f, i}
for each element i in upperdiag:
    for each element j below i, while j is in upperdiag:
        for each element k right of i, while k in is upperdiag:
            function(element j, element k) # do something
```

I.e. "below" the element a includes {e, i, m}, and "right of" a includes {b, c, d}.

I'm having trouble with the indices, and was also wondering whether there was a built-in NumPy function for the iteration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming a square matrix:

```
mat = array([['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'],
             ['e', 'f', 'g', 'h'],
             ['i', 'j', 'k', 'l'],
             ['m', 'n', 'o', 'p']],
             dtype='|S1')

def enum_upperdiag(mat):
   n = len(mat) - 1
   for row in range(n):
      for col in range(n):
         if row + col >= n: break
         for j in range(row+1,n):
            for k in range(col+1, n):
               if j + k > n: continue
               indexOf_j = (j, col)
               indexOf_k = (row, k)
               yield indexOf_j, indexOf_k
```

running

```
[(mat[j], mat[k]) for j, k in enum_upperdiag(mat)]
```

yields

```
[('e', 'b'), ('e', 'c'), ('i', 'b'), ('f', 'c'), ('i', 'f')]
```

if this is acceptable, then you can run it as follows:

```
for j,k in enum_upperdiag(mat):
   function(mat[j],mat[k])
```

this can also be tightened into a single list comprehension:

```
enum_upperdiag = lambda mat: (((j,c),(r,k)) for n in [len(mat)-1] 
                                 for r in range(n) for c in range(n-r) 
                                 for j in range(r+1,n) for k in range(c+1,n-j+1))
```